# Why is my D-Link IP webcam unreachable from within the LAN, but accessible from outside?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, upnp

I recently bought a D-Link DCS-930L network webcam which is connected to my WLAN network. It retrieves a IP address via DHCP from DD-WRT based router (a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND), and it is listed under "Active wireless nodes".

The camera is registered to a webservice called "My DLink", which enables the user to access the webcam from the internet (via their webpage or via smartphone apps). This service works, and I can access the camera from outside.

However, when I try to connect from inside my (W)LAN, it says "No route to host". How is that possible?

--

***EDIT:*** I found the answer by myself accidentally by skimming through the IP webcam settings. It turned out that the option **Setup** > **Network Setup** > **UPnP Port Forwarding** was set to *Enable*. I don't use UPnP in my LAN, and it is disabled on my router.

I don't understand how the enabled UPnP on the webcam could cause troubles, when there were no other devices supporting UPnP. **Has anybody an explanation for this?**

Comment: *No route to host* is a reply from your router, not the Webcam itself. Can you ping the IP address? Can you scan it with nmap? Does it appear as one of the DHCP clients in your DD-WRT router page (under Status -> LAN, active clients)?

Comment: No, I can't ping it, but it does appear as well as DHCP client as WLAN client.  
`imac:~ andreas$ ping 192.168.1.30  
PING 192.168.1.30 (192.168.1.30): 56 data bytes  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4  
^C  
--- 192.168.1.30 ping statistics ---  
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss`

Comment: I can however ssh into my router and ping it successfully from there: `root@lonkero:~# ping 192.168.1.30
PING 192.168.1.30 (192.168.1.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.592 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.658 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.857 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.645 ms

--- 192.168.1.30 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.592/1.938/2.857 ms`

Comment: Can you post your routing table?

Comment: `192.168.100.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0  
10.100.10.2     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0  
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0  
10.100.10.0     10.100.10.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0  
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0  
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo  
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0`

Comment: What really confuses me is the fact that it used to work immediately after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Most of all, you have a very confused routing table. You may wish to erase all of your routes, and let *eth0* acquire a new address via *DHCP*: Then I bet you will see your camera. In other words: I believe the problem lies with your routing table, not with your camera.

Try the follwoing: as sudo,

```
   service network-manager stop
   ifconfig br0 down
   brctl delbr br0 
   ifconfig eth0 down
   ifconfig eth0 up 
   dhclient eth0
   ping -c3 192.168.1.30
```

I think it will work now. In any case, all of the changes above disappear upon reboot.